# Convert audio files for CMU Sphinx 4 input

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I have a big batch of files I'd like to run recognition on using CMU Sphinx 4. Sphinx requires the following format:

- 16 khz
- 16 bit
- mono
- little-endian

My files are something like 44100 khz, 32 bit stereo mp3 files. I tried using Tritonus, and then its updated version JavaZoom, to convert using code from [bakuzen](http://www.bakuzen.com/FileRecognizerForcedAlignment.java). However, `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)` throws an `UnsupportedAudioFileException`, and I haven't been able to figure out why, so I have moved on.

Now I am trying ffmpeg. The command `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ac 1 -ab 16 -ar 16000 output.wav` seems like it should do the trick (except for little endian), but when I check the output with Audacity, it still labels it as "32-bit float". The command I found on [this site](http://wiki.roberttwomey.com/Solipsist_Development) also uses `-acodec pcm_s16le`, which from its name seems to be outputting 16 bit little endian; however, Audacity still tells me the output is `32 bit float`.

Can anyone tell me how to convert audio files into the format required by CMU Sphinx 4?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you actually try the output from ffmpeg in CMU Sphinx 4? 32-bit float is probably your default sampling format in Audacity (*Edit > Preferences > Quality*). I'm guessing it converts any imported file to these settings, so it may not be reporting the parameters of the actual file, but perhaps the working file in Audacity.

Remove `-ab 16`. This would instruct the encoder to use 16 bits/s and ffmpeg will ignore it for pcm_s16le anyway. So your command will look like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output.wav
```

To convert all mp3 files in a directory in Linux:

```
for f in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 "${f%.mp3}.wav"; done
```

Or Windows:

```
for /r %i in (*) do ffmpeg -i %i -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 %i.wav
```

In Windows Batch file:

```
for /r %%i in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 "%i.wav"
```

You can see file information with `file`, `ffmpeg`, `ffprobe`, `mediainfo` among other utilities:

```
$ file hjl0bC.wav 
hjl0bC.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 16000 Hz

$ ffmpeg -i hjl0bC.wav
[...]
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be the correct format. My output files still do not run with Sphinx 4, however. May have to ask @Nikolay Shmyrev directly...

Comment: The format was right. My file just had zero energy level regions, so once I added dither into the frontend everything worked great.

Comment: @NateGlenn I added your edit that was rejected by other users. I'm not a Windows user, so I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks. I guess if my edits are being rejected that I need to review editing policy.