# How to convert Alexa AVS responce output to 8Khz wav OR parse only wave from Alexa output that must detect as wav by Sox for converting

Tags: json, sox, alexa-voice-service, avs

How to convert Alexa AVS responce output to 8Khz wav OR parse only wave from Alexa output that must detect as wav by Sox for converting

im getting error **FAIL formats: can't open input file  ****** : WAVE: RIFF header** not found while converting alexa output to 8kHz wav using sox

Answer (score 0):

The output from Alexa is an mp3. You may need to convert the mp3 to wav file using ffmpeg. Conversion of mp3 to wav file with a particular channel, bit rate setting is present in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358287/how-to-convert-any-mp3-file-to-wav-16khz-mono-16bit)